# Accessing the mobile system app using android

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out an issue in Android. I would like to know how I can access the mobile system applications like gallery, music player,and other apps. I'm trying to build an app that prompts various apps like gallery, music based on an inbox message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify intents, for example Intent for gallery app

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Pick A picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

for music player

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used to open installed application for sharing texts

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody ="Message need to share";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Heading/subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Invite via"));
```

Comment: for more [refer](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/sharing-data-from-your-android-app-with-other-apps.html)